# Microsoft Access: Set a global variable on table open, use it as criteria for queries, and clear it on table close

Tags: ms-access, vba, global-variables

I want to be able to ask the user for a global variable on tableopen on specific tables, use it as a criteria for sub-queries, and clear it on tableclose.

To use it in queries, I've found the getglobal SQL function which should do it fine, however I couldn't find a way to query the variable to the user on table open and clear it on table close.

Any help welcome.

Comment: I'd love to know why the -1 ...

Anyway. I have achieved part of the solution. 

I've made a public function which asks for the site as a global variable it is less then 3 characters long. Otherwise it uses the previously entered value.

I then use it as a criteria. 

[code]Public Function GetCurrentSite()
If Len(Site) < 3 Then
Site = InputBox("Enter Site")
End If
GetCurrentSite = Site
End Function[/code]

However, I still need a way to clear this on "Table close" event... If someone could help...

And please explain the -1 when you feel like puting one. Might be helpful

Comment: I didn't -1, but my guess is that it's related to my 2nd paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this, as there's no way to call a function on table open.  Typically, you would either put a prompt in a query to ask the user for a value when running the query, or have a form set up where the user is prompted for a value, and then open the query/report while referencing the control with the value in it.

Why would you ever let a user open a table??  This is asking for trouble.  Give them a GUI, take their input and run whatever you need to run on the back end.

Comment: Thank you. As you where replying, I edited a comment as you see :) 

For instance, the user is me. I'm the only one using this database, and I don't plan to release it to anyone. It's a tool to help me manage my project. That's why I don't plan to use forms.

Comment: There is no OnClose event of a table.  In fact, there's no OnOpen event either.  How are you running your function?  Where are you putting it?

Comment: It is used as a criteria in the query used as data source for the lookup field.

Comment: There's nothing to clear.  Every time you open this query, it's going to run that code and either prompt you for a Site or read it from the table.  If the first record in the table has a Site with a length longer than 2, it's not going to ask you anything and it's just going to pull that Site.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I want that next time I open the table, I can change the site, but have it asked only once.

Comment: Access can't hold a global variable forever, unless it's hard-coded.  Variables are reset each time you run the code.  The only ways I know to combat that are to write the info to a table or a field on a form, since both are available during your entire session (assuming you use code to minimize a form instead of completely closing it).  I have to stick with my original answer; there's no way to do what you're trying to do.  That's just not how Access works.

Comment: I'm not new to Access... I've been using it since ver. 1. Just not full time  ;-) I guess my request wasn't clear enough. The way I do it works. The variable is asked the 1st time I open a table where the value is needed to filter the lookup field subquery. I just want a way to unset it at some point. I will do a procedure which set the variable, open the table, waits for the table to close, and unset the variable. Just got the idea ;-) Tx anyway for your answers. Luckily there are still people who answer, and do not judge and vote with no comment.